# Python automatic versioning not happening while running in github actions

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi, github-actions, python-3.8

I was trying to push the package from the CI directly to pypi after successful build.
I have tried couple of tools, say "setuptools-scm", everything works well and i get automatic version change based on my tagging like `package-0.0.2.post11-py3-none-any.whl` in my local.

When i push the same code as part of github actions (command `Run python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`) i dont see the versions getting updated and i always get `package-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl`

Below is the snippet of setup.py

```
setuptools.setup(
    name="package",
    use_scm_version=True,
    setup_requires=['setuptools_scm']
```

ymlfile:

```
 publish:
    name: Build and publish Python  distributions  to PyPI and TestPyPI
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python 3.8
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: 3.8
    - name: Install scm version
      run: >-
        python -m
        pip install
        setuptools-scm==4.1.2        
    - name: Install wheel
      run: >-
        python -m
        pip install
        wheel==0.34.2
    - name: Build a binary wheel and a source tarball
      run: >-
        python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
    - name: Publish distribution  to Test PyPI
      uses: pypa/gh-action-pypi-publish@master
      with:
        password: ${{ secrets.test_pypi_password }}
        repository_url: https://test.pypi.org/legacy/
    - name: Publish distribution  to PyPI
      if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags')
      uses: pypa/gh-action-pypi-publish@master
      with:
        password: ${{ secrets.pypi_password }}
```

pyproject.toml

```
# pyproject.toml
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=42", "wheel", "setuptools_scm[toml]>=3.4"]
[tool.setuptools_scm]
write_to = "pkg/version.py"
```

I am not clear what i am doing wrong here, Can any one help to fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you pushing your tags to GitHub as well? Is your action configured to run [`on.push.tags`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestbranchestags)?

Comment: Yes I am publishing the tags on GitHub. I could see it through the web. I have configured to run on push not on.push.tags. will that make a difference ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the action `- uses: actions/checkout@v2` is not fetching the tags along while checking out. Had to additionally add below lines to fetch the tags from git

```
publish:
    name: Build and publish Python  distributions  to PyPI and TestPyPI
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Fetch all history for all tags and branches
      run: git fetch --prune --unshallow
    - name: Set up Python 3.8
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: 3.8
    - name: Install scm version
      run: >-
        python -m
        pip install
        versiontag      
    - name: Install wheel
      run: >-
        python -m
        pip install
        wheel==0.34.2
```

Answer (score 2):

As [kbk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62979328/1860294) said, a shallow copy (one commit) of the repo is checked out by default. Unless the last commit has a tag, tag-based automatic versioning tools have nothing to work with.

Since the `actions/checkout` merged Pull Request #258 [Fetch all history for all tags and branches when fetch-depth=0](https://github.com/actions/checkout/pull/258), you can use `fetch-depth: 0` option with `actions/checkout@v2` to fetch a complete history (including tags) and enable setuptools-scm to correctly deduce version names.

```
  steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      fetch-depth: 0
  - name: Set up Python 3.8
    uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: 3.8
```

Unfortunately, this can be slow for large repos and there's an open issue with `actions/checkout` [#249](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/249) to address this.